# Creating customised button using code behind from Expression Blend

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

what happen was what i normally do from visual studio is to open up expression blend and edit it from there. I created a customised shape and convert it to a button function.

But on the code behind , all i know is i can do a Button btn = new Button(); to generate a new button, what do i need to do to generate that customised shape button that i want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By clicking "Make into control" Blend will create a simple button with a custom style. To create a true control you have to create a new UserControl.